# Stream audio files in php site

Tags: php, audio-streaming

I have a php site I am developing, I uploaded some audio files into a folder on my server and saved their location URL on my database, now I want to call up the audio file in one of my pages and stream it, my major problem here is the line of code I can use to stream out, and let it be functional on mobile browsers as well. thanks as you help me out.

Comment: PHP can't stream music, you need something like flash, html or javascript / jquery to do that sort of work for you, might be worth just usings a generic web based music player which will render in HTML and get PHP to echo out the HTML with the link to the audio file you are wanting to play

Comment: @Sephedo PHP can certainly stream music, and is used to do so on many sites.

Comment: @Jeroen Flamman thanks man, but i am a little confused, can help me with the JavaScript that i should link to the php code u wrote above? thanks for the help.

Comment: @Suleimanabdulrazaq It can deliver a file but if your after browser control then you need something else to do this

Comment: something else? what do u mean specifically?

Comment: Please look this music streaming app using php http://www.appunitz.com/stream-audio-using-php/

Answer (score 3):

On the PHP side, something like this should work - assuming you refer to mp3:

```
   header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
   header('Content-length: ' . filesize('/path/to/your/file.mp3'));
   print file_get_contents('/path/to/your/file.mp3');
```

On the front-end you will then need to look for a Javascript based solution that will actually play the file. You said, it needs to be cross-platform - that's more a front-end (Javascript) challenge than something that can be controlled by PHP.

Comment: Best just to use  your web server at this point... no need for a script if this is your method.

Comment: Not quite true. Using the web server means making the mp3 publicly available. Using the script means hiding the mp3 below the web root and making it available only to the authorized user.

Comment: I would agree if that's what was happening, but that's not the case in this example.  In addition, you can still use sendfile or similar and hand the work off to the web server after doing your authentication, which is much more efficient.

Comment: Well, I run a record label and have about 400 titles that artists need to manage in our backend. The code snippet I suggested works fine for us, all audio can be previewed / played back while logged in and I can go to sleep resting assured my artist's mp3s aren't up for grabs.. I'm sure there is a more efficient way for pretty much everything.. Feel free to answer this person's question.

Comment: No doubt, and your method is actually what I usually suggest to people.  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15480380/362536)  I just like to be very clear on what people need and don't need since people copy and paste code from StackOverflow all the time without understanding it.  Also in your case you would benefit from `readfile()`, if you're keeping things in PHP.  It's much more efficient than loading a whole file in memory and then outputting it.

Comment: @Jeroen Flamman please which java script command should i use? I tried some java script codes and it worked fine on PC browsers but fail to stream on mobile browser, kindly check d link here (9jahotbeats.host56.com/view file.php?id=13)